# Integration: u substitution problem

Tags: integration

I'm trying to integrate the following:

$\int_{0}^{\infty} x^2 e^{-2x}$

I know that $\int_{0}^{\infty} x^n e^{-x} dx = n!$

Feels like a $u$ substitution problem but I'm having trouble making use of the above.

Thanks,
Mariogs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $u=2x$, then $\frac{1}{2}du=dx$. So now
$$\int_0^{\infty} x^2e^{-2x} dx = \frac{1}{2}\int_0^{\infty} \left(\frac{u}{2}\right)^2e^{-u} du $$
$$
= \frac{1}{8}\int_0^{\infty} u^2e^{-u} du=\frac{2!}{8}=\frac{1}{4}
$$

Answer (score 2):

Look at the more general integral, related to Laplace transforms, of this type:
\begin{align*}
\mathcal{L}\left\{t^n\right\}\left(s\right)&=\int_0^\infty t^n e^{-st}\:dt,
\end{align*}
and you may solve using integration by parts to always get something of the form
\begin{align*}
\int_0^\infty t^n e^{-st}\:dt & = \frac{n!}{s^{n+1}}.
\end{align*}
In terms of the Gamma function you wrote,
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^\infty t^ne^{-st}\:dt&=\frac{\Gamma\left(n+1\right)}{s^{n+1}},
\end{align}
which looks somewhat nicer.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Try the substitution $y=2x$, which should reduce it to the form you mention along with a constant factor.

Answer (score 0):

make the ansatz $\int x^2e^{-2x}\,dx=(Ax^2+Bx+C)e^{-2x}$

Comment: why was this downvoted? differentiating both sides you can compute the coeficients $A,B,C$

Comment: i don't no what is wrong