# Integration: Another tricky u substitution problem

Tags: integration

I'm trying to integrate this:

$\int_{0}^{\infty} x^3 e^{-2x}$

I know that $\int_{0}^{\infty} x^n e^{-x} dx = n!$

Does $u$ = $2x$ make sense, and then $x^3$ = $u^3 / 8$?

Thanks,
Mariogs

Comment: Once again, refer to my post in your other question about integrals of the form $$\int_0^\infty t^n e^{-st}\:dt$$ -- there is no need for this second post as I've provided a suitable answer and others have as well. You would be better off integrating this problem by parts rather than continue th pursuit of u-substitution as parts condenses to a single solution for ALL integrals of the type you're asking about.

Comment: bd1251252 has provided a perfect answer for you as I looked back at the questions he's answered including one for you. Here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1026647/integration-u-substitution-problem/1026670#1026670

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**
\begin{align*}
\int_0^\infty t^n e^{-st}\:\mathrm{d}t  
=\int_0^\infty \left( \frac{x}{s} \right)^n e^{-x}\,\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{s}
=\frac1{s^{n+1}}\int_0^\infty x^n e^{-x}\,\mathrm{d}x
\end{align*}
Using $x = st \ \Rightarrow \ \mathrm dx = s \cdot \mathrm dt \ \Rightarrow \ \mathrm{d}t = \mathrm{d}x/s $.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it makes perfect sense to substitute $u = 2x$. If you do that, you must introduce an extra factor $(1/16)$ to get things right. Here $1/8$ is from $x^3 \rightarrow u^3$ and another $1/2$ from $dx \rightarrow du$. You now have the integral in the standard form. Substituting the known result gives you the final answer: $3!/16 = 3/8$.

Answer (score -1):

Try Integration by Parts  3 times